# Retrieve office and windows keys before Full restore

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, microsoft-office, system-restore

I'm working on a computer that has gone straight loco.
It's an upgrade from windows 7 to windows 10. Workedfine at first but now not so much.

It's lagging so much that I can even backup my files (The only oprtion I see here is mounting the HDD on a linux to backup whatever I want. Any suggestion here would be appreciated)

I want to full restore the PC. How can I retrieve Microsoft office and Windows keys so that I can register them later ?

One problem is that I have office 2007. Even if I retrieve the key, will I be able to get it back if  fully restorethe PC ?

The best case scenario I wanna to do is complete legal downgrade to Windows 7 while keeping Microsoft office 2007 >>> everything legal.

ps : I think the PC is an OEM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nirsoft has an application that finds all your keys. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

As far as I know your OEM key is linked to your Motherboard/CPU/MAC-address, so doing a clean install shouldn't be a problem. As for office, if you bought the software reentering the key should also not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have clean installed a number of Windows OS and they always reactivate automatically. My buddy just did that on his W10 upgraded system. If you want the code you can use nirsoft program but it whould be the same as the one on the W7 label on your computer.